# Why is my html form clearing the page contents after ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

The code should work something like this...
https://jsfiddle.net/Harout360/yhqoadqx/7/

But instead the form post does get correctly processed, then it redirects to the "/" url given as the action url in ajax. I can't figure out why it is redirecting, and if I place a console.log in the ajax it doesn't print to console.

HTML

```
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="${title}" />
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub-button" data-loading-text="Loading..." data-complete-text="Submitted!">
    Submit
    </button>
  </form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("button[id=sub-button]").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var button = $(this);
            var form = $(this.form);
            var form_data = form.serialize();
            var form_method = form.attr("method").toUpperCase();
            console.log('subscribing...');          
            $.ajax({
                url: "/", 
                type: form_method,
                data: form_data,
                success: function(){      
                    button.button('complete');
                }           
            });
        });
    });
```

Java Servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String title = req.getParameter("title");
    Database.addTitle(title);
}
```

**UPDATE**
The Javascript works now because my problem was assigning the function to buttons that didn't exist at the time that document.ready loaded. Instead I now assign the .click to the button when it was actually loaded onto the page. Also I changed button's type to button, removed the id and now use $(.movie) to identify the button by its class.

Updated fiddle to give slight understanding of new approach https://jsfiddle.net/Harout360/yhqoadqx/11/

**New Issue**
Now the problem is that button.button('complete') is not doing anything. Any guesses as to why?

**UPDATE 2 (Solution to new issue)**
setTimeout(function() { button.button('complete'); }, 500);

Comment: Change the button type from submit to button

Comment: @Oisin Just tried that, and the button do anything now.

Comment: In your jquery selector just write `#sub-button`

Comment: I have multiple buttons with the same id. So when I do that, only the first button with that id works (at least on jsfiddle). @Oisin

Comment: Why do you have multiple buttons with the same id? ID's are made to be unique! Use classes or at least a `data-xxx` attribute.

Comment: You can't have multiple buttons with the same ID, they are unique

Comment: I can get rid of id completely that's not a big concern.

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console?